# Is there any specific canon info on where Goa'uld larvae come from?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

We know that Goa'uld are born as larvae from their "Queen".

As far as I recall, the only 4 queens mentioned in SG1 canon were:

- [Hathor](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Hathor) (not active since Ancient Egypt and then killed by SG1)

  - Similar for [Isis](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Isis).
- [Egeria](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Egeria) (Only gave birth to Tok'ra)
- [Anubis's Queen](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Anubis%27_Queen) (only produced larvae for Anubis)

Is there any **canon** mention of any non-Anubis-exclusive Queen who **actually produced** Goa'uld larvae **in contemporary times** as opposed to merely being a "female" Goa'uld or carrying "Queen" title?

We know there are larvae produced since Jaffa recieve them. But it appears from what I recall that none of the actually named queens are known to be mothers.

Comment: I also found someone named Dana (I never finished watching SG1 so she may have been in later season) but she also doesn't seem to be mentioned as producing larvae recently.

Comment: Also, whichever queen possessed Sha're, doesn't count. Her offspring was human, not Goa'uld

Comment: How does Hathor not qualify? Prior to SG-1 killing her, she was making larvae in modern times.

Comment: @keen - Hathor hasn't been active since http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/332_BC

Comment: The events of [*Hathor*](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Hathor_(episode)) didn't happen in 332BC!

Comment: @Keen - but in 19** she did not produce any viable Goa'uld larvae that survived (I hope). While that may technically fit the wording in the body, it doesn't fit the purpose of the question as expressed in the title - where DO all the larvae we see implanted in Jaffa come from? NOT from Hathor.

Comment: *Ohh*, you're looking for the source of the larvae inside the modern armies of Jaffa. Okay then.

Comment: @Keen - exactly

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is no. Although there are a considerable number of [Gao'uld queens](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Goa%27uld_queen) seen in the TV (and non-TV) canons, none are seen to be *contemporarily* producing live, viable larval Goa'ulds.

The queens seen (or mentioned) in the show are:

- [Amaunet](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Amaunet) - The mate of Apophis
- [Anubis' Queen](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Anubis%27_Queen) - Not named but seen in Evolution Pt 2
- [Cleo](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Cleo_%28Goa%27uld%29) - Named by Doctor Jackson. Only seen in fossil evidence.
- [Egeria](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Egeria) - The founder of the Tok'Ra movement
- [Hathor](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Hathor) - The mate of Ra
- [Isis](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Isis) - The mate of Seth
- [Morrigan](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Morrigan) - Seen in the episode "Summit"
- [Nut](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Nut) - Mentioned by Vala in the episode Avalon Pt1

Of these eight, four are **definitely** Goa'uld larval queens (i.e. as opposed to merely inhabiting female human bodies); Egeria, Cleo, Hathor and Anubis's Queen.

Of these four, **none** are seen to be producing viable Goa'uld offspring (Egeria and Anubis's queen are producing non-imprinted larvae, Cleo is a fossil and Hathor dies during the process of spawning) which seems to answer your question nicely.

As you've mentioned, we do see some [prim'ta](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Prim%27ta) (larval Goa'uld) in a variety of episodes ("Children of the Gods", "The Enemy Within", "Bloodlines", "Bane", "Reckoning, Part 1, etc) but we don't see the birth mother of any of them.

[image: Anubis' queen]
[image: Egeria]
[image: Cleo]

For the record, we do see a queen called [Anat](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Anat) in the stargate "Living Gods" roleplaying game. She does indeed give birth to live, viable goa'uld offspring but obviously the canonicity of an RPG is highly questionable.

Comment: Also, though we don't see them on screen give birth to new goa'uld, there does seem to be a population management process in place to prevent prim'ta from becoming full goa'uld, as seen in `Summit`.

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest - Certainly that's the implication of Daniel's "Now we know why the population is stable" line.

Answer (score -1):

Goa'uld larvae have a rather sketchy origin all around. Queens produce offspring asexually, yet Apophis has a son in Klorel. This alone makes for a rather weird situation because this would mean that Apophis is either:

A) Not the true father of Klorel, which makes it rather weird that he genuinely seems to care about him, a rare trait for any Goa'uld.

B) He is not only Klorel's father, but also his mother, and Apophis is in fact a Goa'uld queen.

However, it does seem like it is possible to *force* a Goa'uld to have children, as they are being harvested for Titronin (spelling?). Etheria does produce them as blank slates, but that is something the threat of death could easily alleviate. As such, it is my personal belief (which I can't truly back up with any actual facts other than the fact that we barely see any queens) that Goa'uld queens are valuable assets that are hoarded by the Go'auld. While a few might become famous and influential, I believe most of them end up serving as little more than breeding stock with death if they refuse.

Comment: Why shouldn't Klorel just be the HUMAN offspring with memories from the Goa'Uld larvae? I mean... just because of a larvae controlling him, he remains his... you-know-what-i-mean...

Comment: Because Klorel's host is Skaara, who is an Abydos human. So the host is clearly not his son, which means the larvae has to be.

Comment: The Goa'uld may practice adoption, possibly for political reasons. There are several apparent family groups in *Children of the Gods* and Apophis has at least two off-spring; Klorel - mother unknown - and Heru'ur, with Hathor. Then there's the *Harsesus* (sp?) who is the son of Apophis' host. Goa'uld familial relationships clearly suffer from a lack of planning during the early seasons, which is unfortunate for continuity purposes.